# how to download subtitles from a m3u8 file which is protected by cloudflare?

Tags: ffmpeg, m3u8

I am trying to use ffmpeg to download a vtt file from an m3u8 link but it isn't working

i tried to run ffmpeg -i https://manifest-gcp-us-east1-vop1.cfcdn.mux.com/nCuL1I6vazd2gTqez6v8cW96dY6kB02KK2i008fUX5L8EjUpCcCJagIoZ2Uu01cAZFC0102nF5SzBm8M/subtitles.m3u8?cdn=cloudflare&expires=1687752000&signature=NjQ5OTBkNDBfYTExYTNkOTRlZTg1ZWU0NjUwZWUzNGFiMzFkZDgyNDFkMzU2OGU0YmExZGQzZGIyNWE5MjJkMGE3ZTdmOTM3YQ== output.vtt but it didn't work and gave me:

Error when loading first segment 'https://chunk-gcp-us-east1-vop1.cfcdn.mux.com/v1/subtitle/nCuL1I6vazd2gTqez6v8cW96dY6kB02KK2i008fUX5L8EjUpCcCJagIoZ2Uu01cAZFC0102nF5SzBm8M/0.vtt?skid=default&signature=MF9lY2EwNmQxODg5OGQ5MTQxY2E1NjU2MDNiOTdkNDBhMGJjNzU1N2EwOGQ2N2E1MmE2NTI0Y2Y5MTQxNDZlYjc2'
https://manifest-gcp-us-east1-vop1.cfcdn.mux.com/nCuL1I6vazd2gTqez6v8cW96dY6kB02KK2i008fUX5L8EjUpCcCJagIoZ2Uu01cAZFC0102nF5SzBm8M/subtitles.m3u8?cdn=cloudflare: Invalid data found when processing input

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as the ffmpeg tag states: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/. Please delete this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp), you can get your subtitles :
`yt-dlp  "https://manifest-gcp-us-east1-vop1.cfcdn.mux.com/nCuL1I6vazd2gTqez6v8cW96dY6kB02KK2i008fUX5L8EjUpCcCJagIoZ2Uu01cAZFC0102nF5SzBm8M/subtitles.m3u8?cdn=cloudflare&expires=1687752000&signature=NjQ5OTBkNDBfYTExYTNkOTRlZTg1ZWU0NjUwZWUzNGFiMzFkZDgyNDFkMzU2OGU0YmExZGQzZGIyNWE5MjJkMGE3ZTdmOTM3YQ==" -o subtitles.vtt`

Comment: thank you so much your the only answer on the internet!